# Why does AIX on Power require that the svc instruction must be preceded by an unconditional branch or a CR instruction?

Tags: aix, assembly, powerpc

The [IBM AIX Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.3?topic=set-svc-supervisor-call-instruction) for the `svc` (Supervisor Call) instruction has a note that states

> To ensure correct operation, an svc instruction must be preceded by an unconditional branch or a CR instruction.

Why is this required?

Comment: Because it is documented to be required. Do you understand the documentation preceding that *Note:*?

Comment: @JaromandaX, I would imagine it works the other way round. It's documented as required because there is some technical reason that requires doing it that way. One doesn't usually pull requirements out of their hats to add in documentation. The note doesn't say such a requirement exists, and nothing in the preceding text seems to hint at the reason either, as far as I can see.

Comment: I think I understand the documentation preceding the note, but I don't see how it explains the requirement.  I don't understand the relationship between an unconditional branch and updating the CR register, so that combination seems strange.  Since the `svc` instruction does update the CR register it seems unhelpful to have modified it right before the call.  The system call instructions in the Power ISA do not have this restriction.